# curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)

Tags: curl, proxy, tor, socks5-proxy

I'm using [zeta0/alpine-tor](https://hub.docker.com/r/zeta0/alpine-tor/), yet I am getting mixed results while trying to access two separate `.onion` address(s):

```
# docker run -d -p 5566:5566 -p 2090:2090 -e tors=25 zeta0/alpine-tor
fd7f92d139c9170371c55dff31d1d9350261cfd4326014b6f471edd9f392814e
# docker exec -it tor fd7f92d139c9170371c55dff31d1d9350261cfd4326014b6f471edd9f392814e
/ # apk --quiet --no-cache add curl
/ # curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:5566 facebookcorewwwi.onion -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
X-FB-Debug: 7YhJnMZiUK7PyDeM9Yg5+PSpCC+8MH+Nt2W+yzY0Hy0ggaU9hMqCjlyWQJcT8MI4+yJS43QotG/Mb1+fasf98w==
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 19:27:06 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

/ # curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:5566 X.onion -v
* Rebuilt URL to: X.onion/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* SOCKS5 communication to X.onion:80
* Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)
/ #
```

---

- `X.onion` was obfuscated due to security reason.
- `X.onion` works via `Tor Browser` without any issues.

Please advise.